# How can I color the area between 2 curves?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pythonplotter

I'm trying to color the area between 2 fitted curves that I've plotted. Here is my code, though I can't include the data I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xp = np.linspace(-6.0, 0.0)

bestfitup = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 9))

bestfitdown = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(xdata, ydata, 9))

plt.fill_between(xp,bestfitup, bestfitdown ,color='#539ecd')
```

[image: Picture of curves]

However I get the following error:
`ERROR: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (50,) (10,)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill area between two curves in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969088/fill-area-between-two-curves-in-python)

Comment: Hi. yes. but I can't fix that yet!